# RegEx to match phrases with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, search, match, regex-group

I have an array of keywords in strings:

```
var keywords = ["Hello World", "or"];
```

and I have a line of text, e.g.:

```
var text = "Hello World, Hello World";
```

I am using RegEx to find the keywords in the text to highlight so that my resulting html would be:

```
<span class="highlight">Hello World</span>, <span class="highlight">Hello World</span>
```

However, my RegEx result is returning me this:

```
[
 0: "or"                          ----------> shouldn't it be "Hello World"?
 index: 7
 input: "Hello World, Hello World"
]
```

This is my code:

```
function searchFn(text, keywords) {
  regex = new RegExp(keywords.join("|");
  return regex.exec(text);
}

var text = "Hello World, Hello World";
var keywords = ["Hello World", "or"];

searchFn(text, keywords);
```

Is my RegEx wrong?

Comment: Use `regex = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + keywords.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
}).join("|") + ")\\b", "g");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort the keywords by length in descending order, use **unambiguous word boundaries**, global modifier to match all occurrences and use it in a `String#replace` method like this:

```js
function searchFn(text, rx) {
  return text.replace(rx, '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>');
}

var text = "Hello World, Hello World,Hello (World)!";
var keywords = ["Hello World", "or", "Hello (World)"];
var regex = new RegExp(
 "(^|\\W)(" + 
 keywords
  .map(function(z) { return z.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'); })
 .sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })
 .join("|") +
")(?!\\w)", "g");
console.log(searchFn(text, regex));
```

The regex will look like `(^|\W)(Hello World|or)(?!\w)` and will match `Hello World` or `or` words as whole words. Since you have special characters, you need to [escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) in the keywords, and use *unambigous word boundaries*, `(^|\W)` and `(?!\w)`, which requires specific replacement pattern, namely, `$1<span...>$2</span>`, since we do not want to truncate out the non-word char captured into Group 1 if it matched. Sorting is necessary in case you have both `Hello World` and `Hello` / `world` and you want to handle longer keywords first.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I've tried your code and the RegEx is still not detecting my "Hello World" neither the "or" in it anymore..
The regex looks like this: `/\b(?:Hello World|or)\b/g`

Comment: @est Exactly, that is what the regex should look like, and it matches `Hello World` or `or` as whole words.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. Prior to that, it didn't work for me because I tried playing around by adding special characters in between the text. So if I have an array of keywords like this: `["Hello (World)", "or"] and text like this: "Hello (World)", how can I modify the RegEx to fit such cases?

Comment: @est I modified the solution to account for that, too.